# How to install Postgre SQL DB instance in AWS? Where I can find Postgresql installation package for AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql

I have a AWS account where I want to install Postgre SQL DB instance for a POC project. Is there any Postgreq SQL installation package available for AWS? What are my steps to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
from the AWS page.[Create and Connect to a PostgreSQL Database](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/)

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/

Comment: Thanks. Is there any special Postgresql installation package for AWS?